# Having trouble connecting a function to an animation player (Godot)

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a `Player` node that has a child node `AnimationPlayer` that has an animation called `water_right`.

I also have another node called `Crop` that has a texture of a seedling. Inside of my `Crop` node I have a variable called `is_watered: bool = false`. Inside of my `_ready()` function inside the `Crop` node I have this:

```
func _ready():
    if is_watered:
        $Sprite2D.texture=ResourceLoader.load(image)
```

When I run the `water_right` animation (by pressing a button) I want to run a function called `water()` that simply changes the value of `is_watered` inside my `Crop` node to `true` that way the image changes. I'm using the call method to add a function and a key that activates right before the animation ends but I can't figure out exactly how to run the function inside the animation player.

Comment: You want a [call method track](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/animation/animation_track_types.html#call-method-track). You "I can't figure out" but that sounds to me that it you figured it out but didn't get the result you expected. Does `water()` change the texture? Addendum: in fact, did you try a `print` in `water()` to confirm it was called when the animation plays?